# Finding if two strings are anagrams or not in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that checks if a string is an anagram or not. However I keep getting error's That "you cannot assign to a variable that is constant". I understand what it means, but what is the walkaround/solution for this?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    bool check_str(const string& a, const string& b)
    {

    // cant be the same if the lenghts are not the same 
    if (a.length() != b.length())
        return false;
    //both the strings are sorted and then char by char compared
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) //char by char comparison
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string a = "apple";
    string b = "ppple";

    if (check_str(a, b))
    {
        cout << "Yes same stuff" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not the same stuff" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
 }
```

Comment: a and b are constants. You can not sort them.

Comment: Along with the answers you've already gotten, note that you don't need to explicitly compare char by char. Just `return a == b;` will compare the characters individually.

Comment: What is the point of that edit? Also, as already mentioned, this `if ... else...` you just added at the end of your function can be reduced to `return a == b;`.

Comment: I removed your confusing edit.

Answer (score 7):

You try to `std::sort` your input strings which would modify them, but you also declared them `const` (by passing them as `const std::string&`) which prohibits modifying them.

Pass by value, i.e.

```
bool check_str(string a, string b)
```

or non-const reference, i.e.

```
bool check_str(string& a, string& b)
```

instead. The latter will modify your original strings, the former won't. Also, the first variant will accept temporaries and the second one will not.

In my opinion, passing by value would be the way to go here as some function called `check_str` modifying its inputs seems counter intuitive.

Last remark: As already mentioned in the comments, you do not need to use a loop to compare the strings, you can simply compare them with `a == b`.

Answer (score 0):

Both strings are constant references, but you try to sort them. That obviously changes the strings, therefore is not valid. You could make copies of your string, or pass by value instead of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since the string are const, you can not sort them. 
Make a copy of them may be a workaround, but I think when the string are large, it make the space complexity O(n), and if you want to sort, make the time complexity O(nlgn). I prefer this approach, time O(n), space O(1):

```
#define SIZE CHAR_MAX + 1
bool check(const char a[], const char b[]) {
    if (strlen(a) != strlen(b)) return false;
    int length = strlen(a);
    int char_count_a[SIZE] = {0};
    int char_count_b[SIZE] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) char_count_a[a[i]]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) char_count_b[b[i]]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) 
        if (char_count_a[i] != char_count_b[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof(char)` is what you want there, and not something like `CHAR_MAX + 1`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yep... Mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool check_str(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    if (a == b)
        return true;
    std::string temp(a);
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    while (std::next_permutation(temp.begin(), temp.end())
        if (temp == b)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ye olde `O(n!)` algorithme.

Comment: It will take days to check strings with hundreds chars, oops

Comment: awesome solution - now write it in ook! :-))

Comment: @Barry - yes, but it only copies one string instead of two. <g>

Answer (score 0):

Simplest working code, with const reference argument

```
bool check_str(std::string const &a, std::string const &b) {
    if (a == b)     return true;
    std::string t1(a);
    std::string t2(b);
    std::sort(t1.begin(), t1.end());
    std::sort(t2.begin(), t2.end());
    if(t1 == t2)    return true;
    return false;
}
```

or with pass-by-value

```
bool check_str(std::string a,std::string b) {
    if (a == b)     return true;
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    if(a == b)    return true;
    return false;
}
```